# Creating a frame made out of a single letter

Tags: css

I am styling a website and as I have been focusing on the back office lately I am not sure how to achieve this.. Maybe someone can help me

Main div is 1000px wide. And would like to create a border for this div which is made of a single letter. I think it would give a raw look, instead of adding a padding with a color to it.

it would look like this:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@                            @
@                            @
@                            @
@                            @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Is there a way to achieve this easily. Considering the fixed-width div can be adjusted to devices and therefore its width may vary..

Comment: http://border-image.com/ maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [border-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image) to accomplish something very close to what you want. I say very close, because of the dynamic resolution of the div, so chances are that some of the characters will be cropped.

You can add the `round` option to the rule in order to prevent any character cropping:

> **Bitmap repeated (round)**
>
> The round option is a variation on the repeat option that distributes the tiles in such a way that the ends nicely connect.

Useful article showing how to create the image itself: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/#article-header-id-10

In your case, it would consist of 8 `@` signs forming a square.

Comment: Seems good, I will try this. And playing with images doesn't seem a problem because I don't plan anything dynamic here... thanks

Comment: You're welcome! This is actually more powerful than I expected (as you can see my answer edits) and in fact it can do **exactly** what you want. The only downside is that you can't use a font to render it, but an image... I suppose you could use canvas to generate an image from an actual font character, but not sure it's worth it.